# How can I display the current keyboard map on screen?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm using setxkbmap to switch between keyboard mappings English and Hebrew:

`setxkbmap -option grp:lwin_toggle -option compose:rwin us,il`

I would like a little indicator of the current map on-screen.  It could be as simple as "il" or "us" in the corner.  How can I do this?

Edit: I'm not using Unity, I'm using fvwm2.

Comment: What desktop environment ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using unity. Open Dash and search for keyboard and open **Keyboard**
[image]

Click on **layout settings** and add the keyboard layout by clicking "**+**"

Once you set the extra keyboard layout, you can see a small icon of the top panel(Next to battery icon).
 [image]

When you toggle the layout you can see the indicator showing the active layout (I used the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: I'm not using Unity.  Maybe there's a simple program that can pop open small window that I can populate with whatever text/pic/font that I want?  I can write the script to update it as needed.